# Auto-submit kendo autocomplete widget on select

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I use kendo in angularjs. When I select from the [autocomplete widget](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index) I want to submit the selected value in my form directly. When I write a text into the form (even if the text is not suggested by the autocomplete) enter should always submit the form.

A small example of the code, without angularjs:

```
<form>
    <input id="items"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var names = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 10","Item 20"];

$("#items").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: names,
    ignoreCase: true
});
var autocompleteFacility = $("#items").data("kendoAutoComplete");

$("form").submit(function(event) {
    alert("Submitted item: "+$("#items").val());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8qhb57u/6/

Bonus: I want to decide if the selection was done with keys (enter) or with a mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that working with the close event. On which you have a property ("_last") which is the last pressed key. So I can decide if a the selection did occur with a mouse or the enter (also if no selection was made)

```
autocompleteFacility.bind("close", function() {
    if(this._last === 13) {
        console.log("selection by enter");
        // autosubmit when enter used
        $("form").submit();
    } else {
        // if mouse is used, do nothing
        console.log("selection by mouse");
    }
});
```

Fiddle with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fx2eprqv/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [change](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#events-change) event

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8qhb57u/7/)

```
..
    change: function(e) {
        $("form").submit();
  }
..
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I tried that before and it this does not work with the mouse. Write "Ite", then click "Item 20" and you will submit "Item 1".

Comment: Also (thanks to your answer) I found out that my real-code does not use suggest. So your answer does, unfortunately, not work in my code at all. I changed my question accordingly.